# How to force Rspec/Capybara to load current data into a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

My `survey#show` view is working in production and development but failing in test.

I have:

**/app/views/survey/show.html.haml**:

```
#{@survey.current_score} out of #{@survey.available_points}
```

**/spec/features/survey_spec.rb**:

```
visit competitor_survey_path(@competitor, @survey)
@survey.current_score.should == 1.0 # passes! yay!
@survey.available_points.should == 3.0 # passes! yay!
page.should_have_content "0.0 out of 0.0" #passes! huh???
page.should have_content "1.0 out of 3.0" #fails! huh???
```

How is this even possible? (As I said, it works fine in production and development.) And more to the point, how do I fix it?

I've tried adding `@survey.reload` to the example and `- @survey.reload if Rails.env.test?` to the view.

PS, here is my **/spec/supports/spec_helper.rb**:

```
require "rubygems"
require "database_cleaner"
require "pry"
require "plymouth"

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rspec/rails"
require 'declarative_authorization/maintenance'
include Authorization::TestHelper

require "capybara/rspec"
require "capybara/rails"
require "capybara/dsl"

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.fail_fast = true

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.before(:each) { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.clear }
  config.use_instantiated_fixtures = false 
  config.include(Capybara, :type => :integration)

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

  config.after do
    if example.metadata[:type] == :feature && example.exception.present? && page.current_path.present?
      save_and_open_page
    end
  end

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

end

def login_as(role)
  @role = Role.create! :name => role
  @virginia = User.create!(
    :username => "Virginia", 
    :password => "password", 
    :password_confirmation => "password", 
    :email => "example@example.com")
  @assignment = Assignment.create! user_id: @virginia.id, role_id: @role.id
  visit login_path
  fill_in "user_session_username", :with => @virginia.username
  fill_in "user_session_password", :with => @virginia.password
  click_on "submit_user_session"
end
```

Comment: Have you checked the content of `page.html` in the test, to see what capybara is seeing?

Answer (score 0):

rspec doesn't render the views by default. If it is extremely necessary check how you should do it in the documentation: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-2/docs/controller-specs/render-views

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have blamed Rspec -- it's Capybara's visit method. I just updated the title of my question to reflect this.

Comment: @steven_noble - It's a Capybara visit method, but it's RSpec (or perhaps the rspec-rails gem) that is configuring Rails such that views are not rendered for controller specs by default.  Search for "rendered by" at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails and read that paragraph.

Comment: OK, sure. But the problem is not my view not being rendered. The problem is that when my view is rendered, it says "0.0 out of 0.0" not "1.0 out of 3.0". I've updated above to make this clearer.